# How to create nested dicts in order to create mapping for Elasticsearch by Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I'm trying create mapping by using Loop for handling nested dictionaries.

My mapping form should look likes values below.

```
 { 
    "mapping": {
    "properties": {
        "clusterName": {
            "properties": {
                "infoAddr": { "type": "string" },
                "usedSpace": { "type": "string" },
                "capacity": { "type": "int" },
                "version": { "type": "string"},
                "used": { "type": "int"},
                "remaining": { "type" : "int"},
                "volfails": { "type": "int"}
            }

          }
      }
  }
}
```

And here're my data got from REST API

```
{
    "test.mydomain_1.xyz:1019": {
                                "infoAddr":"x.x.x.x:1022",
                                "usedSpace":384635032546,
                                "capacity":30697676811776,
                                "version":"2.7.3.2.6.5.23-1",
                                "used":384635032546,
                                "remaining":30311575148182,
                                "volfails":0 },
    "test.mydomain_2.xyz:1019": {
                                "infoAddr":"x.x.x.x:1022",
                                "usedSpace":384635032546,
                                "capacity":30697676811776,
                                "version":"2.7.3.2.6.5.23-1",
                                "used":384635032546,
                                "remaining":30311575148182,
                                "volfails":0 }
}
```

Now I have lists of

```
1. clusterName = ("test.mydomain_1.xyz:1019", "test.mydomain_2.xyz:1019",..."test.mydomain_n.xyz:1019")
2. Properties under properties field = ("infoAddr", "usedSpace",..."volfails")
3. Type of values from properties = ("str","str",..."int")
```

Please suggest me how to create mapping from those data by using loop for make this mapping automatically create by itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = {}
for cluster_name, data in a.items():
    type_data = {key: {'type': type(value).__name__} for key, value in data.items()}
    result[cluster_name] = type_data

mapping = {"mapping": {"properties": result}}
```

So, output for the provided data would be:

```
{
    "mapping":{
        "properties": {
        "test.mydomain_1.xyz:1019": {
            "infoAddr": {"type": "str"}, 
            "usedSpace": {"type": "int"},
            "capacity": {"type": "int"}, 
            "version": {"type": "str"},
            "used": {"type": "int"}, 
            "remaining": {"type": "int"},
            "volfails": {"type": "int"}},
        "test.mydomain_2.xyz:1019": {
            "infoAddr": {"type": "str"}, 
            "usedSpace": {"type": "int"},
            "capacity": {"type": "int"},
            "version": {"type": "str"},
            "used": {"type": "int"}, 
            "remaining": {"type": "int"},
            "volfails": {"type": "int"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to map that source from elasticsearch log to specific form, us intended in the dict mapping you show in your post, usually, you need to create some form of recursive visitor, to be able to use it for dicts with arbitrary nesting and info about type of the fields if the mapping might be applied.

For example you may create some kind of function, as below:

```
def visit(data):
    data_mapping = {}
    for data_key, data_value in data.items():
        if isinstance(data_value,dict):
            if data_key not in data_mapping:
                data_mapping[data_key] = {'properties': {}}
            data_mapping[data_key]['properties'] = visit(data_value)
        else:
            data_mapping[data_key] = {
                'type': data_value.__class__.__name__
            }
    return data_mapping
```

Next, call the function on elasticsearch logs dictionary:

```
mapping = visit(data)
mapping = {'mapping': { 'properties': mapping}}
```

Thus, the output will be:

```
{'mapping': { 'properties': {
  'test.mydomain_1.xyz:1019': {
       'properties': {
             'infoAddr': {'type': 'str'},
             'usedSpace': {'type': 'int'},
             'capacity': {'type': 'int'},
             'version': {'type': 'str'},
             'used': {'type': 'int'},
             'remaining': {'type': 'int'},
             'volfails': {'type': 'int'}
        }
  },
 'test.mydomain_2.xyz:1019': {
         'properties': {
               'infoAddr': {'type': 'str'},
               'usedSpace': {'type': 'int'},
               'capacity': {'type': 'int'},
               'version': {'type': 'str'},
               'used': {'type': 'int'},
               'remaining': {'type': 'int'},
               'volfails': {'type': 'int'}
          }
  }}}
```